# How to get a list of the unique keys for a table in SQL Server with PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I want to get a list of the following metadata information for a table in SQL Server using PowerShell:

Column Name, Is nullable column, Is primary key, Is foreign key, Data type and Is Unique (or belongs to part of the unique key)

Currently I'm using the following without getting the information of the unique key:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyComputer\DEFAULT\Databases\MyDB\Tables\dbo.MyTable\Columns> Get-ChildItem | select Name, Nullable, IsPrimaryKey, IsForeignKey, DataType
```

I would like to get something like the following

```
Name         : MyID
Nullable     : False
IsPrimaryKey : True
IsForeignKey : False
DataType     : int
IsUnique     : True
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an IsUnique property however, it is a property of an index and indexes are properties of tables. So if you want to use the SqlProvider, here's a way you can grab the columns which are part of a unique index and then add property to your column output:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyComputer\DEFAULT\Databases\MyDB\Tables\dbo.MyTable>
$UQColumns = get-item . | foreach {$_.indexes} | where {$_.IsUnique} | foreach {$_.IndexedColumns} | select -expandproperty Name
cd Columns
Get-ChildItem | select Name, Nullable, IsPrimaryKey, IsForeignKey, DataType, @{n='IsUnique';e={$UQColumns -contains $_.Name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it using PowerShell, but I think that you should look into the [Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) section on MSDN, especially the [Object Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). To make an idea, here is a code snippet you can use to get informations about the columns of a table named `SomeTable`:

```
select c.*
    from sys.objects o
        inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = o.object_id
    where o.type = 'u' and o.name = 'SomeTable';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to be able to use other filters using PowerShell.